# Control is undefined in Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a control with the correct ID in my .aspx page. But when it is called in a function, it says that it is undefined.

Control:

```
<div class="form-group" runat="server" id="divResult" visible="false">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Result</label>
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <p class="form-control-static">
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litCount">0</asp:Literal>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Function:

```
function showMsg() {

    hidePleaseWait();

    if (xhr && xhr.readystate !== 4) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = null;
        xhr.abort();
        callBackend();
    }

        var hidListFolder = document.getElementById('hidListFolder');
        hidListFolder.value = "";

        $("#btnGenerate").button('reset');
        document.getElementById('btnGenerate').disabled = true;
        divResult.Visible = false; <-- error
        divGenerated.Visible = false;
}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**
Retrieved divResult by the following, and it is `null`

```
var divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');
console.log("divResult: " + divResult);
```

Comment: Try selecting the element and putting it into a `divResult` variable first?

Comment: @CertainPerformance let me try!

Comment: Newer browser do allow direct access to the id, but it is poor practice and why not be consistent, you already do `var hidListFolder = document.getElementById('hidListFolder');` or since you are using jQuery, be consistent with it and try `$("#divResult").hide()` and use $.ajax

Comment: My guess is you have the ID more than once.

Comment: Lastly what is this? `$("#btnGenerate").button('reset');` ???

Comment: @mplungjan following your advice and searched for the id,only declared once :O

Comment: @CertainPerformance my divResult is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

When you are using runat="Server" and server side control render on browser it's id or name changed so if you want to access via id in js use like this

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('<%= divResult.ClientID %>');
```

**Solution 2**

if you do not want to change JS code use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to not change id and name for specific control below

```
<div class="form-group" runat="server" id="divResult" ClientIDMode="Static" visible="false">
```

Answer (score -2):

Get `divResult` element by :

```
var divResult = document.querySelector("#divResult");
```

Comment: or `var divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');`

Comment: Retrieved divResult value and it is NULL